# Java: Find out which class handle which URL call

Tags: java, security, jersey

I need to make a custom filter to my Jersey code... so, in this class

```
package com.test.security;

@Path("/secured")
public class Test {
    @POST
    public void postData() {}
}
```

I want to make this class below to find out which class handled `/secured`

```
public class SecurityFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
    //
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest http = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        System.out.println("session: " + http.getSession().getId());
        System.out.println("method: " + http.getMethod());
        System.out.println("url: " + http.getContextPath());
        System.out.println("class handler: " + <?????> );
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    //
    }

}
```

That should output

```
method: POST
url: /secured
class handler: com.test.security.Test
```

In short, when client requested a URL, I want to find out which class is responsible for it.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Besides, doesn't Jersey log that anyway?

Comment: I need to create custom filter for per module CRUD security. If the client doesn't have right to access that module, it should send access forbidden error

Comment: You would have to hardcode it with a `Filter`. Jersey might have an `Interceptor` interface which it uses to execute before the handler. Look into that.

Comment: yes, I know, but how can I find out its handler class being called, because that's what I store in our table.